# Woocommerce: use add_to_cart hook only for certain product id?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can't seem to find the correct syntax. Here's my pseudo code:

```
function myfunction1() {
    if(product_id_being_added_to_cart = '101') {
        perform stuff;
    }
    else { }
}
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'myfunction1');
```

Basically, I want the hook to fire only for a specific product being added to cart. I just can't figure out the proper way to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    function myfunction1() {
      $product_id_being_added_to_cart = wc_get_product( $post->ID );
        if($product_id_being_added_to_cart === '101') {
            perform stuff;
        }
        else { }
    }
    add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'myfunction1');
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the global `$post` (which you didn't declare anyway) as items can be added to the cart via ajax. Rather the `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook passes the product ID as [one of its parameters](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L951).